# '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get' in CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I'm thinking that this is not the right way to do things, but I am trying to learn django and I am trying some things out. I am trying to set a foreign key for my `Formula` model, by hardcoding in an instance of `maker`.

Models:

```
class Cooker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, name="name")
    background = models.CharField(max_length=500, name="background")


class Formula(models.Model):
    food = models.CharField(max_length=200, name="food")
    maker = models.ForeignKey(Cooker, related_name="cooker_key")
```

Views

```
class CookerCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = "cookercreate.html"
    model = Cooker
    fields = ['name','background']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cooker')

class FormulaCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = "formulahome.html"
    model = Formula
    fields = ['food']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('formulahome')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit = False)
        self.object.maker = Cooker.objects.get(pk=1)
        form.save()
        return reverse_lazy('formula home')
```

In the `FormulaCreate` class where I am setting `self.object.maker`, I just want to hard code in a `Cooker` that I already created. Thanks

EDIT: When I try to submit the form in my `FormulaCreate(CreateView)` I get the error `Exception Value: '__proxy__' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: You've already hard-coded it to use the `Cooker` that has `pk=1`. What do you want to do differently?

Comment: please see my edit thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason for your error is that `form_valid` should return a `Response` object, and you are returning a URL.

Rather than do this manually you should just call the parent method which will redirect to the `success_url` that you have already defined:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit = False)
    self.object.maker = Cooker.objects.get(pk=1)
    form.save()
    return super(FormulaCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: This definitely worked thanks so much. So we are making the `Response` object the `FormulaCreate` instance `self`? And then telling it the form for this instance is valid and Django automatically will go straight to the `success url` right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `Response` object is generated by the parent [`form_valid` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid), so we don't have to.

Comment: I misread the first time, I understand now. This is the same that is in the  [Form Handling with Class Based Views Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the post method return redirect('formula home') works too.