# DRF - How to get created object in CreateAPIView

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-generic-views

My goal very much resembles to what has been asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875917/how-to-get-created-object-in-createview) but from the perspective of DRF, rather than forms.

So basically the question is, how can I get the newly created object in the following code snippet:

```
TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = TestModel


class TestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(TestView, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        created_model_instance = .... ?
        print(created_model_instance.id)
        return response
```

Comment: still wondering if anyone got an answer to this

Answer (score 2):

You can override `perform_create` and use `serializer.save` to get the created object, like:

```py
class TestView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Some doc here!"""
        obj = serializer.save()
        print(obj.id)
```